# Массив в ассемблере

Tags: массивы, ассемблер

```
arr      dw  100 dup (0)  ; массив слов
ind      dw  0            ; текущий индекс массива

mov bx, ind
mov arr[bx*2], ax         ; записать значение ax в массиве
inc ind
```

Результат:

> `**Error** test.asm(238) Illegal indexing mode`

Как правильно?

Comment: Как вариант - попробуйте arr[ebx*2]

Comment: А может лучше полный листинг посмотреть?) 

    mov arr[bx*2], ax 

эт точно строка 238?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Организация и функционирование вычислительных машин](https://studfiles.net/preview/893999/page:8/)

> Косвенная адресация с масштабированием
>
> Этот метод адресации полностью
>   идентичен предыдущему, за исключением
>   того, что с его помощью можно
>   прочитать элемент массива слов,
>   двойных слов или учетверенных слов,
>   просто поместив номер элемента в
>   регистр:
>
> ```
> mov ax,[esi*2]+2
> ```
>
> Множитель, который может быть равен 1,
>   2, 4 или 8, соответствует размеру
>   элемента массива - байту, слову,
>   двойному слову, учетверенному слову
>   соответственно. Из регистров в этом
>   варианте адресации можно использовать
>   только `ЕАХ`, `ЕВХ`, `ЕСХ`, `EDX`, `ESI`, `EDI`,
>   `ЕВР`, `ESP`, но не `SI`, `DI`, `ВР` или `SP`,
>   которые можно было использовать в
>   предыдущих вариантах.

То есть, как правильно заметил skegg, тут подойдет `mov arr[ebx*2], ax`